# Unable to have an equivalent of A(FG p) and AG(EF p)

Tags: logic, linear-temporal-logic, temporal-logic

It states in my lecture notes that there is no CTL formula that is equivalent to **A(FG p)** in LTL and likewise, there is no LTL formula that is equivalent to CTL formula **AG(EF p).**

I am just starting to pick up LTL & CTL and cannot figure out why it is not possible. Could someone shed some light?

**A(FG p):** I would read it as 'All path will eventually globally satisfy p.

**AG(EF p):** For all computational states, globally, there exists a path the will eventually satisfy p.

Am I interpreting it wrongly?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. Why does that make you think you can translate the two formulas to the respective logics?
Start from the second formula. How would you (try to) express it in LTL?

Comment: @Shaull I would think that if a path in LTL that will eventually satisfy p, it should satisfy AG(EF p) since its the only path. Or am I not suppose to intepret it that way?

Comment: ah, so what you're missing is the definition of equivalence: two formulas are said to be equivalent if they give the same truth value for *every* structure. That is, you cannot fix the structure and show that the two formulas agree on it, you have to show that every structure that satisfies one of them, satisfies the other, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Shaull Could you provide me with an example of how a LTL and CTL could be equivalent to help reinforce what you mentioned?

Comment: Well, when two formulas are equivalent, it's usually easily visible. For example, the CTL formula $AGAFp$ and $AGFp$ are equivalent (this is easy to prove).

Comment: Let me try prove it, thanks alot @Shaull!